# Spring boot Eureka in docker swarm registering wrong internal docker ip’s

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm, netflix-eureka

Docker nodes are registering with inter ip’s in `springboot-eureka`.

My conf is as follows:

- Spring-boot eureka deployed to swarm (1 node)
- Created spring-boot client containers (2 nodes) and registering with eureka

[image]

Comment: I edited your question to make the image visible, but keep in mind that it's better to add the actual text / code. For more check these: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you for edit the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the actual external ip address as following:

1) `docker run  -d -p 5555:5555 -h 192.168.x.xx imagename`

and in the yml file

2) prefer-ip-address: true

Comment: Could you please see the above answer Same porblem we are facing.

Answer (score 0):

we are deploying container using  Docker service.

docker service create --name eureka-registry -p 8982:8982 eureka-registry

so it's showing to different IP like;
1: service has own IP
2: the container has its own IP

[image]